# MySql use the column number to generate a password

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, md5

For my little homework webpage I want to set up a login. The login will be the student's name, like:

张聪明

and the student's number, like:

1925010101

These are both in the table 19BE1. I have added a column: password

The database is called allstudentsdb

Now I would like to add each entry under number + allstudentsdb then MD5('number + allstudentsdb')

This does it for the first student:

> UPDATE 19BE1 SET password = MD5('1925010101allstudentsdb') WHERE number =
>   1925010101;

I tried like this:

> UPDATE 19BE1 SET password = MD5('number + allstudentsdb');

but I ended up with a column of identical passwords!

Any tips please?

Comment: Are the passwords `2d70d2c0ea66274ee5b0f3ebcad953a0` everywhere ?

Comment: No, all different. Different input, different output.

Comment: *"I ended up with a column of identical passwords"* That's not what you said in your question

Comment: That was using my useless attempt. With the advice from GMB it worked great! I keep a text file of all commands that work, so I don't have to come back and ask again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this want you want?

```
UPDATE 19BE1 SET password = MD5(concat(number, 'allstudentsdb'));
```

That is, you should be passing the *value* of column `number` to the function, not string `'number'`.